# exFAT pagefile.sys size Error on dualboot with Windows 8.1

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, mount, windows-8, exfat

I have a dual boot with Ubuntu 14.04 running beside Windows 8.1. I store all my data on an exFAT-formatted partition so I can access them from both of my OS'es. It worked fine for the longest time, but now, all of a sudden, Ubuntu refuses to mount the partition. The mount fails with the following error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/peter/DATA: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sda4" "/media/peter/DATA"' exited with non-zero exit status 1:
stdout: `FUSE exfat 1.0.1
'
stderr: `ERROR: `pagefile.sys' real size does not equal to size (0 != 8589934592).
'
```

Is there anything I can do to remedy this? I have the proper libs for exFAT installed, as said, it worked for a long time.

Comment: Peter,  If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!

Answer (score 0):

Boot to Windows and run a:

```
CHKDSK /F X:
```

where `X:` is the drive letter under Windows...

If that doesn't help, right-click on <kbd>Computer</kbd>, <kbd>properties</kbd>, <kbd>advanced</kbd>, <kbd>swap file</kbd>, re-create Windows swap file....

(Ubuntu question, Windows solution) and I would convert ntfs the drive....  FAT just has too many problems.  It's Windows95 technology after all...  :-(

Comment: There are cases where FAT are superior - if you need really old legacy support for instance :P

Comment: I understand...  If it works, don't forget to upvote my answer!  :P  ;)